# Crash when I re-enter a TableViewController due to an attempt to write to what I think is a mutable dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following nested mutable dictionary which I create and save into NSUSerDefaults

```
self.configDict is {
    objectsDict =     {
        "40E1507D" =         {
            lastUpdate = "2015-05-30 05:02:40 +0000";
            subObjects =             {
                "D84EA15E" =                 {
                    lastUpdate = "2015-05-30 05:02:40 +0000";
                    show = 1;
                    title = subObjectOne;
                };
                "F20047D4" =                 {
                    lastUpdate = "2015-05-30 05:02:40 +0000";
                    show = 1;
                    title = GreenObject;
                };
            };
            title = Default;
        };
        "9EE82B8F" =         {
            lastUpdate = "2015-05-30 05:02:40 +0000";
            subObjects =             {
                "AEF3F442" =                 {
                    lastUpdate = "2015-05-30 05:02:40 +0000";
                    show = 1;
                    title = YellowObject;
                };
            };
            title = Other;
        };
    };
    lastUpdate = "2015-05-30 05:02:40 +0000";
    showAllObjects = 1;
}
```

In my table view controller, when I first enter it (viewDidLoad), I load up NSUserDefaults as such

```
self.configDict = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Config"] mutableCopy];
```

In my .h, I have the dict defined as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *configDict;
```

I then proceed to update some fields in there say the lastUpdate time:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subObjectDict = objectsDict[@"40E1507D"][@"subObjects"][@"D84EA15E"];
subObjectDict[@"lastUpdate"] = [NSDate date];
```

This all works well, and I wrap things up with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The crash happens when I exit the table view controller and re-enter it. The above code re-executes as described above, but as soon as I hit the statement:

```
subObjectDict[@"lastUpdate"] = [NSDate date];
```

It crashes with the following error:
2015-05-29 22:53:30.029 myApp[12837:128350] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:

Is it because I have nested dictionaries and the mutable copy is not performing a deep copy?  Why would it work the first time when I read the dictionary from NSUserDefaults, but when I re-enter the TVC it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `mutableCopy` on the outermost dictionary, but that won't make the inner dictionaries mutable - they will still be immutable dictionaries, because that is what is returned by `NSUserDefaults`.

My guess is that the first time through your code the sub-dictionary doesn't exist or is otherwise nil - it is hard to say without seeing more code.  Regardless the exception method is pretty clear - you are attempting to mutate an immutable object, so you need to make a mutable copy first.

Comment: I implemented a deepcopy and the issue went away.  However, the first time the TVC was called I guarantee you the nested dictionary existed.  I suspect a compiler bug where on the re-entry into TVC it does not perform the same copy as it does the first time.

Comment: I doubt it is a bug. Probably a better solution is to use core data rather than NSUserDefaults

Comment: Agreed with regards to coredata.  I forgot what a pain nested dictionaries can be as I have been working in python for a while.